# Can a \newcommand Definition Contain Braces as Substitution Text?

Tags: macros, braces, grouping

The following example is completely counter-intuitive, but I need this in a bigger definition I'm not including here.

```
\newcommand{\openbrace}{{}
```

I need this to start a nested scope.

Is this possible in LaTeX? I'm getting an error because the TeX engine is viewing this as unbalanced number of braces.

Comment: It would help to know what you need it for.  If you just want the symbol, then you could use `\newcommand{\openbrace}{\{}`.  If you want to start a group you could use `\newcommand{\openbrace}{\begingroup}`

Comment: I edited the question. I need to begin a new scope.

Comment: Does the second option I mentioned above work for you in that case?  Actually, just `\begingroup` might be easier..

Comment: Yup. Can you please change it to an answer? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the intention is to start a new group then you can use

```
\newcommand{\openbrace}{\begingroup}
```

or, more simply, just

```
\begingroup
```

To close the group, the corresponding macro is `\endgroup`