# Splitting a command syntax across a \newenvironment definition

Tags: environments, braces, grouping

This question is a direct follow-up to the question [Can a \newcommand Definition Contain Braces as Substitution Text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119820/can-a-newcommand-definition-contain-braces-as-substitution-text) I asked yesterday.

The following example is once again a counter-intuitive one, to demonstrate what I wish to achieve. I'm trying to split the `parbox` syntax across the begin code and end code of a `newenvironment`. Using `begingroup` and `endgroup` does not seem to work here, and is producing an error.

```
\newenvironment{mybox}{\parbox{10cm}\begingroup}{\endgroup}
```

Is this possible in LaTeX?

Just to elaborate a bit on my specific need, I need a lot of **centered**, **framed** boxes to highlight some "warnings" and "best practices". For this, I thought of the following environment:

```
\newenvironment{mybox}[2]%
{%
  \begingroup \centering \fbox \begingroup \parbox{10cm} \begingroup #1 \hspace{5pt}
  {\large \textbf{\textsf{#2}}} \hfill \\
}%
{%
 \endgroup \endgroup \\ \endgroup \vspace{5pt} %
}
```

One of the arguments is for switching between the texts "Warning" and "Best Practices", and the other one is to provide a special symbol for each type (like a star or as shadowed box)

Comment: Use `\begin{minipage}{10cm}` and `\end{minipage}`

Comment: Actually I needed to put the `parbox` inside an `fbox`, and further, needed to center the framed box using `{\centering .... \\}`.

Comment: This is a job for the auxiliary environment `lrbox`; please state more clearly the real problem, because your simplification was too, well, simple. ;-)

Comment: Added my specific situation!

Comment: You want to have a look at the `mdframed` package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted in comments the standard `minipage` and `lrbox` environments are designed for this use, or for the particular case of framing a box, `mdframed` package.

To note why the definition shown does not work, you can not delimit macro arguments with `\begingroup`.

```
 \fbox \begingroup
```

is the same as

```
 \fbox{\begingroup}
```

and passes the `\begingroup` token as the content of the box. After that things are bound to go wrong.

Similarly

```
\parbox{10cm} \begingroup
```

is

```
\parbox{10cm}{\begingroup}
```

with `\begingroup` being passed as the argument to `\parbox`.

Comment: `mdframed` seems to be the answer to the problem. However there is a frame rendering issue in the resulting pdf, in that the frame is missing some sides with different zoom levels. Also, using symbols from the `bbding` and `MnSymbol` packages with `mdframed` is giving an error `Missing $ inserted`. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Chatterjee: The zooming levels have nothing to do with LaTeX, but with the viewer and is a way of optimizing the visual layout. Printed versions will include all the necessary lines though.

Comment: @Chatterjee the lines going is a feature of the viewer, the problem with math is most likely that you have a missing `$`.