# How to operate the words inside an environment?

Tags: macros, environments

As title goes, I want to find a way to get the access of the words inside the environment. To be exactly, given some command `\operate` with one variable, I want to define an environment `foo` such that

```
\begin{foo}
This is the inside words. 
\end{foo}
```

outputs like `\operate{This is the inside words. }`. 
Roughly speaking, I want a command help me get access to the words between `\begin{foo}` and `\end{foo}`. 
This problem is fundamentary in some ways.

- If the command is empty, it is just what the package `comment` did. (Note that it is impossible to define `\newenvironment{comment}{\iffalse}{\fi}`, since the expansion of `\fi` is later than `\iffalse`)
- If the command is `\fbox{#1}`, it is just what the package `mdframed` did. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120058/152446) explain why it is not easy .

I try to figure out a solution as follow

```
\newenvironment{foo}{}{\endgroup}
\long\def\foo#1\end{\begingroup\noindent\fbox{\vbox{#1\unskip}}\end}
\begin{foo}
This is the inside words.
\end{foo}
```

But the problem is that we cannot use other environment inside this environment.

Comment: The [`environ`](https://ctan.org/pkg/environ) package does this.

Comment: Using `\NewEnviron` (from the `environ` package), the contents of the argument are contained in `\BODY`.  You can likely, in the environment, say `\expandafter\operate\expandafter{\BODY}` to get `\operate` to operate on the contents of `\BODY`..

Comment: Do you want this to handle things like `\verb|This is verbatim|` also?  (That is something the environ-packe does not afaik.)

Comment: And what about the space tokens that due to the `\endlinechar`-thingie come into being at the ends of lines, e.g., at the end of the line `\begin{foo}` or at the end of the last line within the environment `foo`?